# Get user total starred count using Github API v3

Tags: github-api

From the [doc](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/), I can list repositories being starred using:

```
GET /users/:username/starred
```

But it seems that I can't directly get the count of total starred repos of a user.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a very interesting question, and I think I have found the answer to it. Let us use the [GitHub top user](https://gist.github.com/paulmillr/2657075/) chart to randomly choose [Ocramius](https://github.com/Ocramius) with their 299 starred repos, available in JSON form from [this address](https://api.github.com/users/Ocramius/starred).

Now let us try querying the headers through `curl -I "https://api.github.com/users/Ocramius/starred"`. We get one hopeful-looking header:

> Link: https://api.github.com/user/154256/starred?page=2; rel="next", https://api.github.com/user/154256/starred?page=10; rel="last"

This header comes from [the pagination feature of the API](https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/), so what happens if we ask for one record per page with `curl -I "https://api.github.com/users/Ocramius/starred?per_page=1"`?

> Link: https://api.github.com/user/154256/starred?per_page=1&page=2; rel="next", https://api.github.com/user/154256/starred?per_page=1&page=299; rel="last"

Aha! If we parse this [RFC5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988) HTTP header, we can strip out the page number tagged as `rel="last"` and we have the correct answer of 299!

Comment: This is surely a possible and clever way. I'm still open for more convenient and straightforward way. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @skyline75489 I just emailed GitHub support to see how reliable this is. I'd argue, however, that it's just as convenient and straightforward as, and slightly less network overhead than, doing a `GET` then parsing the JSON return. Furthermore, this technique should work for all API that don't explicitly return counts.

Comment: @skyline75489 GitHub support says "We recommend the same approach to users who are interested only in the total count, so it's safe and reliable in that sense for endpoints which support pagination and the "last" rel.", so  it seems you can use it safely. They also said they don't envisage adding a direct "count" field or endpoint.

Comment: All right then. I'll accept this answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

A suggestion to `Ken Y-N`'s answer:

When the user has only one or zero starred count,the api will response without the `Link` header.

So when response has not the `Link` header, you can directly to get the starred count from the `JSON-ARRAY`'s length in the response body.It just can be 0 or 1.